# ¿Como funcionan estas dos funciones recursivas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este es un ejemplo de recursividad donde una funcion llama la otra que esta a su vez llama a la otra , pero no entiendo muy bien

```
def is_even(x):     
   print(x)
   if x==0:
      return True
   else:
      a = is_odd(x-1)
      print(x,a)
      return a

def is_odd(x):
    print("esto")
    return not is_even(x)

print(is_even(3))
```

Comment: Pero aca no hay nada de recursividad. Creo que deberias revisar la definicion de funcion recursiva (que es una funcion que se llama a si misma) y te recomendaria mirar [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque una forma un poco extraña la implementación, en esencia **el algoritmo es recursivo**, aunque no la función estrictamente hablando. Tanto es así, que si das un valor a `x` mayor de 1000 te encontrarás con el límite de recursión preestablecido en Python:

```
>>> is_even(1000)
# ....
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Esto se debe a que se enlazan llamadas a funciones alternativamente, pero ninguna puede retornar hasta que a última llamada lo haga, igual que pasa en una función recursiva.

En realidad, la función `is_ood` no tiene utilidad alguna más que complicar todo un poco más, es solo un envoltorio para llamar a `is_even` de nuevo y negar su retorno, realmente sería lo mismo que:

```
def is_even(x):     
   if x == 0:
      return True
   else:
      return not is_even(x - 1)
```

que si es una función recursiva propiamente dicha, se llama a si misma de forma directa.

Para explicar la secuencia voy a limpiar ambas funciones de prints:

```
def is_even(x):     
   if x == 0:
      return True
   else:
      a = is_odd(x - 1)
      return a

def is_odd(x):
    return not is_even(x)

print(is_even(3))
```

Si seguimos el algoritmo paso a paso:

1. Se llama a `is_even` pasando 3 como valor de `x`.
2. Como 3 no es cero se pasa al `else` y se ejecuta `a = is_odd(x - 1)`.

   **La asignación a `a` queda a la espera hasta que retorne `is_odd(3 - 1)`**
   **`return a` queda a la espera de que la línea anterior termine**
3. Se llama a `is_odd(3 - 1)` -> `is_odd(2)`. Se ejecuta por tanto `return not is_even(x)`.

   **El retorno de ésta llamada queda  a la espera de que retorne `is_even(2)`**
4. Se llama a `is_even(2)`, como 2 no es cero se pasa al `else` y se ejecuta `a = is_odd(x - 1)`.

   **La asignación a `a` queda a la espera hasta que retorne `is_odd(2 - 1)`**
   **`return a` queda a la espera de que la línea anterior termine**
5. Se llama a `is_odd(2 - 1)` -> `is_odd(1)`. Se ejecuta por tanto `return not is_even(x)`.

   **El retorno de ésta llamada queda  a la espera de que retorne `is_even(2)`**
6. Se llama a `is_even(1)`, como 1 no es cero se pasa al `else` y se ejecuta `a = is_odd(x - 1)`.

   **La asignación a `a` queda a la espera hasta que retorne `is_odd(1 - 1)`** 
   **`return a` queda a la espera de que la línea anterior termine**
7. Se llama a `is_odd(1 - 1)` -> `is_odd(0)`. Se ejecuta por tanto `return not is_even(x)`.

   **El retorno de ésta llamada queda  a la espera de que retorne `is_even(0)`**
8. Se llama a `is_even(0)`, como `x` es 0 se ejecuta el `if` y se retorna `True`.

   Ahora se resuelven en orden ascendente todas las operaciones pendientes hasta llegar a la llamada original `is_even(3)` que termina retornando `False`.

Quizás quede más clara la secuencia así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]